# Good book on Partial Differential Equations

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I know that this question was already asked. But I am looking for a book on partial differential equations that covers the basics . And specifically explains reduction to **canonical forms** with examples.

Comment: Here you go https://www.math.brown.edu/~mgulian/morris-tenenbaum-harry-pollard-ordinary-differential-equations-copy.pdf and it's free.

Comment: The book in the link was completely ordinary differential equation . I want partial differential equations

Comment: you obviously didn’t read the chapter labeled partial differential equations.

Comment: Here is another free book: http://sharif.ir/~moosavi/A%20First%20Course%20In%20Partial%20Differential%20Equations%20-%20H%20F%20Weinberger%20-%20Dover%20Publications.pdf

Comment: Ohh sorry checked again

Comment: The [book](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Methods+of+Mathematical+Physics%3A+Partial+Differential+Equations%2C+Volume+2-p-9780471504399) *Methods of Mathematical Physics: Partial Differential Equations, Volume 2* by R. Courant and D. Hilbert is a classical reference on the topic (see [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=fcZV4ohrerwC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) to get an insight), but it may not fit well for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

V. I. Arnold Lectures on Partial Differential Equations

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at *Partial Differential Equations in Mechanics 1* by A. P. S. Selvadurai.

This book

- covers the basics in chapters 2 and 3.
- explains reduction to canonical forms in [Section 4.2](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=kd15BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&dq=partial+differential+equations+%22reduction+to+canonical+forms%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAxeuqk7bgAhUgI7kGHfjlApUQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=partial%20differential%20equations%20%22reduction%20to%20canonical%20forms%22&f=false).
- gives examples in [Section 4.3](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=kd15BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA132&dq=partial+differential+equations+%22Reduce+the+partial+differential+equation+to+a+canonical+form%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX45zGlrbgAhVvD7kGHapPCUwQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=partial%20differential%20equations%20%22Reduce%20the%20partial%20differential%20equation%20to%20a%20canonical%20form%22&f=false).